# Webkitdirectory file selection limits in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, upload

I am attempting to use the HTML5 Files API and JavaScript to run a massive upload using the webkitdirectory attribute.

```
<input type="file" class="left files file-input" name="dir" id="dir_input" webkitdirectory="" directory="" multiple="">
```

Ideally in the end a user could upload an entire hard drive with one action. I have a test data set of 750k documents of varying size and file extension in a folder. When I select the folder via the Browse for Folder Dialog, Chrome pauses for awhile and goes dark gray. There is no error logged in developer tools and there is no message given.

I am assuming this is happening because the directory selected had too much information. I have tried uploading 100k .txt files and it went smoothly. However the 750k random file types (.pdf, .xls, .doc, etc) causes this error.

I was wondering if anyone knew if there was a limit, and if so what is the limit, and ultimately is there any way to remove or alter the limit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This runs into a HEAP limit issue in chrome.  You can only read so many files because chrome runs out.